# fread fails with VS2008 64-bits

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit, libc

I'm currently porting a software from 32 to 64-bits using Visual Studio 2008 and I'm encountering an issue regarding `fread` which causes a segfault when called:

Here is a code sample reproducing this issue:

```
void somefunction(std::string filepath)
{
    FILE* myfile = fopen(filepath.c_str(),"rb"); // returns a valid handle
    if (myfile)
    {
        char* buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE+1];
        memset(buffer,0,BUFFER_SIZE+1);
        fread(buffer,1,BUFFER_SIZE,myfile); // segfault happens here
        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

`GetError` and `ferror` do not report any error and the file can be read when compiling for 32-bits. It always triggers a segfault when entering `fread` on 64-bits though.

I've tried several other file reading methods (with `ifstream` and Qt's `QFile`) and they work.

Unfortunately, `fread` is used in many other places in the code and I would like to know if there is something peculiar with its implementation for VS2008 64-bit before changing every bit of code that uses it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you confirm [this sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92651aad7e8bc4d0) from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt0etdcs.aspx) (adapted to actually be C) does not work on your system? Also, you're not checking the return value of `fread`. And you don't need to allocate the buffer with `new`. Just do `char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE+1];`

Comment: Don't see anything wrong in this function itself. Are you sure you're not clobbering something in a different function, and it just happens to crash in this one? [Or your example may be too simplified?]

Comment: I've identified this issue in various areas, everytime fread being the culprit.
As this code is part of a closed-source product, I'm unfortunately not able to show larger code samples :/
In addition, changing the fread call with ifstream fixes the problem, so I'm guessing this is really coming from fread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys I think I figured it out.

Seems this issue was related with msvcrt linking on Debug mode.

The fread call was located inside a library linked against msvcrtd.lib while the executable from where the error was raised was linked against msvcrt.

I'm kind of surprised this was only causing issues with fread. Are the libc symbols located inside msvcrt under Windows ?

Anyway, I'm currently cleaning my link flags. Sorry not to have been able to post a more detailed code sample. We are working under very strict NDAs and I did not excpect this to be related to the link flags ^^'

Comment: `msvcrt` reads MicroSoft Visual C Run-Time. So yes, `msvcrt` (and the compiler-version specific `msvcr*` are "libc".